# how to not return an item on array if it is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that given an ids i want to return its' corresponding object, this is the code:

```
var x = {gf:[1,3]};
var {gf} = x;

var todos = [{id:1,fg:"aaa"},{id:2,fg:"bbb"},{id:3,fg:"ccc"}];

var fg = (gf) => {
  var f = todos.reduce((todoArray,todo) => gf.includes(todo.id) ? [...todoArray,todo] : todoArray, []);
  return f;
}
console.log(fg);
```

I wanted to return the variable f, but fg is a function? This code works, but I cannot do it because this is a resolve method for graphql:

```
var f = todos.reduce((todoArray,todo) => gf.includes(todo.id) ? [...todoArray,todo] : todoArray, []);
console.log(f);
```

I tried immediately invoked function but it doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe use `filter()` and `typeof variable != 'undefined'` as a condition.

Comment: i think filter would not work since it's analogous to reduce? don't know why it's returning function

Comment: Are you referring to this line: `console.log(fg)` when you say its returning a function? If so you need to invoke the function, not pass a reference to it to console.log: `console.log(fg(gf))`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to, if i run your code with the following change: `console.log(fg(gf))` its working. The output is an array with 2 objects in it, which is the fiist and third elements of the `todos` array.

Comment: @Sasang thanks, graphql is confusing I wanted to return iffe which is wrong,